# how can I make rewrite rule to write my domain name to have caps on certain letters?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

for example:

mydomain.com/whatever

to show like

MyDomain.com/whatever

can i do with with a rewrite rule in htaccess?

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mrhowtosay\.com/([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.MrHowToSay.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it loops infinitly

Comment: Do you understand what `!` does at the beginning of a rule?

Comment: nope, i copied it from someone else rule i found this site

Answer (score 0):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is *only* the hostname submitted through the "Host:" request header. It doesn't contain any URI path info. So the `/([^&\s]+)` bit will cause the condition to guarantee fail (which negates to always "true"). Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.MrHowToSay\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.MrHowToSay.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: shouldnt the rewrite condition have all lower case?

Comment: your answer also seems to be looping infinitly

Comment: @user1397417 No, it shouldn't be lowercase because the `!` means, "not". Thus if the requested hostname is *not* `www.MrHowToSay.com`, redirect it to `http://www.MrHowToSay.com/`. And it doesn't loop for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/D2iDg.png